# Show that interval is an event.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega =[0,1] $and we know that sets $[0,x]$, $0≤x≤1$ are events. Show using the properties of event space (sigma-algebra) that $(1/2,2/3)$ is also an event.

I just started to study probability theory and I'm not really sure what I should do here. I'm really grateful if somebody could explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the event space is a sigma-algebra, it's closed under countable unions and intersections. This means that if you can "construct" (1/2, 2/3) out of sets you already know belong to the event space, then you are guaranteed to have it in the sigma algebra.

The usual trick for making an open set out of closed ones is to take a limit of nested (or somehow related) sets. For example:
$$
\cup_{n=1}^\infty{{\left[0, \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{2^n}\right]}} = [0, 2/3),
$$
so $[0, 2/3)$ is in the event space.

Finally, $[0, \frac{2}{3}) \backslash [0, \frac{1}{3}] = (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$.

(A sigma-algebra is closed under differences because $A\backslash B = A \cap B^c$.)

Comment: It's just [0, 2/3 - a], with a = 1/2^n! I've edited the notation to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now.